# axios doesn't send post data to the back-end

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm new to react and.my problem is that i'm going to make a post request to my node back-end. using react-redux and axios. the thing is my back-end doesn't even hit the request. and no action on the network tab in the browser ether

I have tried lots of another answers but doesn't work

this code is in my redux action page

export const postNominationPayments = function

postNominationPayments(candidatePayments) {

```
let nominationPayments = {

    depositor:candidatePayments.depositor,
    depositAmount:candidatePayments.depositAmount,
    depositeDate:candidatePayments.depositeDate,
    filePath:candidatePayments.filePath,
    status:candidatePayments.status,
    nominationId:candidatePayments.nominationId

};


return function (dispatch) {
    console.log("**",nominationPayments);
        var headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
     axios
        .post(
            `${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/payments`,
            {
                nominationPayments
            },{headers: headers}
        )
        .then(response => {
            console.log("))))))))))))",response);
            // dispatch({
            //     type: POST_NOMINATION_PAYMENTS,
            //     payload: response.data
            // })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("===",error);
            // dispatch({ type: AUTH_FAILED });
            // dispatch({ type: ERROR, payload: error.data.error.message });
          });



};
```

}

post data is coming as expected.also the back works correctly using postman. but it's not working. 
couldn't think of a solution.
what is wrong with my code?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing data to axios post request is incorrect. You need to pass something like below

Change

```
  axios(
        `${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/payments`,
        {
            nominationPayments
        },{headers: headers}
    )
```

To

```
  axios.post(
       `${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/payments`,
         nominationPayments,
         {
              headers: headers
         }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 axios.post(
            `${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/payments`, nominationPayments,
             {headers: headers}).
```

One can drop headers section as well a default is `application/json`

Comment: when i remove the return function (dispatch) {} part it works..why is that

Comment: How do u calling this function?

Comment: if (activeStep === 2){
      postNominationPayments(this.state);

Comment: call it using ,     this.props.dispatch(postNominationPayments(this.state));

Comment: that was the issue.. previously i didn't call like this.props.. now it's working..thanks

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` and `axios.post` takes different kind of arguments and could be hard to remember.

So I usually just stick to the more verbose way:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: `${API_BASE_URL}/nominations/payments`,
  data: {
    nominationPayments
  },
  headers
})
  .then(response => {
    // ...
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // ...
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your MongoDB server is up and running?

In my case, my React server was running, however, my MongoDB servers were not. I ran both simultaneously and was able to post data to the back end.